# How to make echo on Java socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server and client program, which Client can send message to server. So, how to make the Server that can send back any response message to client?

This is the Server Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Handler updateConversationHandler;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    private TextView text;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Client code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.177.102";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the socket Stream same way as the client..

you can do in the run method

```
PrintWriter pw;
pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
String read = input.readLine();
pw.println(read);
pw.flush();
```

Comment: Sir, would you like to give the complete code? because i'm not fully understand. Which run method should i do this? Does the client need to do the inputStream?